# customize multi-dimension array debugging in visual studio 2015 with .natvis file

Tags: c++, debugging, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015, natvis

I am using arma Matrix and I would like to have a look at the value during debugging.
So I add a natvis file as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="arma::Mat&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ Size = {n_rows} x {n_cols} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]">n_elem</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Direction>Backward</Direction>
        <Rank>2</Rank>
        <Size> $i==0?n_rows:n_cols </Size>
        <ValuePointer>mem</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

However, it doesn't work at all.

Sooner I relize the problem may be

```
<Size> $i==0?n_rows:n_rows </Size>
```

So I try to replace it with any of the following statements and it works

```
<size> $i==0?5:8 </Size>    
<size> $i==0?n_rows:8 </Size>
<Size> $i==0?5:n_cols</Size>
```

However, if I try any of the following statements, I get nothing again

```
<size> $i==0?n_rows:n_cols </Size>
<size> $i==0?n_rows:n_rows </Size>
```

By the way, I've turned the Natvis diagnostic messages to "Error" in options but nothing is there in the error list.

Thanks for any help

Comment: my understanding is that it would be not an error, it just means that the debugger window couldn't recognize the specific tags/property parameter under the ArrayItems, you could view this sample about how to use "ArrayItems Expansion" here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2

Comment: Thanks Jack, but it only give an example of 1D array. Besides, I've read the MSDN explanation and they used size[$i] in the <size></size> filed i.e. they store the size in a 1*2 array so that it can be called without a if statement. However, I am using armadillo and the matrix size is defined by two ints instead of an array.

Comment: can you share me a simple sample using one drive? I will debug it in my side using the same Environment as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to int solved this for me:

`<Size> $i==0?(int)n_rows:(int)n_cols </Size>`